# How to Import Excel multiple sheet in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, excel, vba

I want to register user in mvc5 through excel sheet so i have multiple sheet in a single excel file.So i am not able to get how to Import multiple sheet to multiple table in order to register a user and its other information.

```
     public ActionResult ImportUser()
      {
        if (Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength > 0)
         {
          string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);

           string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
              if (fileExtension == "" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                 {

             string path1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFolder"), Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
             Request.Files["FileUpload1"].SaveAs(path1);
             string sqlConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path1+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
             if (dt == null)
               {
                  return null;
               }
           String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
           int t = 0;
              //excel data saves in temp file here.
           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
              excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
              t++;
            }
             OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnectionString);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
             using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
              {
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
               }                  
               for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
               {                        

           SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
           sqlc.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Planetskool-20140309125429.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Planetskool-20140309125429;Integrated Security=True";

 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IdentityUser (Id,UserName,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp)  VALUES(@Id,@UserName,@PasswordHash,@SecurityStamp)", sqlc);//@OB_ID is indentity primary key

cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Id"]).ToString();
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["UserName"]).ToString();
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["PasswordHash"]).ToString();
 cmd2.Parameters.Add("@SecurityStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["SecurityStamp"]).ToString();
                  sqlc.Open();
                  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  sqlc.Close();
```

Comment: Please go through this thread which would be helpful, [How to import all the Excel sheets to DataSet in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006318/how-to-import-all-the-excel-sheets-to-dataset-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the code like below it may help you

```
    public void ImportXLX()
        {


                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\Sheets\MyXL6.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    int workSheetCounts = wb.Worksheets.Count;

                    for (int sheetCounter = 1; sheetCounter <= workSheetCounts; sheetCounter++)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = wb.Sheets[sheetCounter];
}
}
```