# How can I select a set of rows and columns from an excel sheet in query for C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel

I want to select the following data from excel:

Rows : 3-7
Columns : C-W

How can I write a query to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are asking to get data from excel. Simple way would be (if not simplest) Load your Excel File sheets in DataSet's DataTable and then read the DataTable accordingly.
Row index 0-6 and Column Index 2-22

here's [how to load Excel in Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006318/how-to-import-all-the-excel-sheets-to-dataset-in-c-sharp)